# Simulink Code Generation C++ get signal values from Scope

Tags: c++, matlab, code-generation, simulink

I have a Simulink model from which I generate C++ to Visual Studio.

The Simulink model has a scope block at the end of the calculations, which gets two signals whose values interest me in C++

Now I have searched the C++ Code for these two signals, but only find signals from intermediate calculations, not the signals for the scope.

How can I find them?

Comment: Depending on which code generation target you have used, adn whether those signals are being logged, then they may not appear in the generated code.

Comment: @PhilGoddard thanks, the **System target file** is `grt.tlc` with `C++` for Visual Studio. Is there any way to ensure that the signals appear in the generated code?

Comment: I haven't used `grt` for a long time, but my memory (which could be faulty) is that signals going into *viewers* (such as the `Scope` block) get ignored during code generation unless their data is being logged.  So you should either log the data, or send it to an `Outport`.